# Which is it - CURA or Cura?

Tags: discussion

I see a number of people writing "CURA", when I have always called it "Cura". So I started to wonder if CURA was a *capitalised* acronym, like LiDAR or NATO (but not like radar or laser).

I had a look and the Wikipedia entry, [Cura (software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cura_(software)) doesn't appear to suggest that.

So I wondered if it was a marketing thing.

---

After all, over on SE.Arduino, *lots* of people write "Arduino UNO" - I myself did so to, for a long time, until Nick Gammon [picked me up on it](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13839/can-i-use-analogreadresolution-on-an-uno-or-leonardo#comment25114_13839):

> [image: Uno not UNO]

I *think* that the reason that I did was that the Arduino pages write it in that way (arguably incorrectly) and it just seems to be a branding/marketing ploy.

So, is this the same sort of thing with CURA? I am just wondering where it started and came from?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> As one does on a boring rainy Sunday morning :-)

Comment: I don't think this is an acronym, but be aware that acronyms are spelled differently in Britain and in USA.  For example, "Nato" and "NATO", or 'Aids" and "AIDS".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 4 the splash screen has changed, also the branding/naming of the product throughout Ultimaker's website.

[image]

Technically it is not *CURA* or *cura*, it is *Ultimaker Cura*.

Comment: Huh, I wish they'd make their minds up, about what its name is, and not keep changing it! :-)

Comment: They rebranded the software and names, there is a posting on their own forums somewhere, but I couldn't find it. This is the name they stick with! For now that is ;-) I think that now Ultimaker has established itself very well in the 3D printer market that it is not going to change.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's neither:

[image]

If you wanna believe this image, it's: Ultimaker **cura** ... all lower case.